# vb.net - send image to android device in soap response

Tags: android, vb.net, image, soap

So I would like to get an image as a response from my webservice but I cant figure out how to send back the image data using ksoap. Should I send it back as a byte array? can I send it back as a byte Array? I know that when dealing with images in ksoap on android you start to run out of memory really quick so being that I may need 60 or so images this may be a problem. Ive done this before using php and apache/java stuff and it was super easy compared to figuring out how to do the same in vb.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert the image to a `byte array` and send it that way. You will probably only be able to send one image at a time though

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Bitmap bitmap = Images.Media.getBitmap(
                        getContentResolver(), uri);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, stream);
                byte[] arry = stream.toByteArray();
                String aryString = Base64.encode(arry);
```

Comment: Ill have to try to see but do you think setting up an asynctask to run through the process getting images individually would be a decent solution

Comment: This doesnt work with soap as I cant get the service to return a byte array without crapping out

Comment: this does work I do it in my application convert to a byte array and send the byte array as a string

Comment: I added code, basically take the bitmap, compress it, turn it to byte array, encode it to a string

Comment: Thank you for the code but I can already handle the data once it gets to the device. My problem is I cant get vb.net to output the full image. It stops in mid transmition and wont give a full return value. In debugging my service I can see on the server that the string starts off like a normal base64 encoded array to string and then stops leaving a huge white space before the end of the xml doc that it spits out.